# Get parameters value from another url

Tags: php, cgi

In a `.cgi` file I set  `$HTTP_PROXY= '192.168.1.1:80'` how can I get `192.168.1.1:80` from a text file on another host or url (for example line 4 data.txt in http://url.com/data.txt ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to READ the contents of that file you can use

```
$raw  = file_get_contents('http://urlcom/data.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $raw);
echo $file[3]; // read line 3
```

The file MUST be accessible (by your host/system/etc).

Comment: thanks but how define which line of that text file ?

Comment: `$file = explode("\n", $str); echo $file[4];`